# Do I have to use induction for this set proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $B\subset A_i\subset A$, then$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i\subset A$ and $B\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_i$

Maybe i can use the fact that if $A,B\subset A, then A\cup B \subset A$, but does tihs require induction? can someone post a proof in which you take an element on one set and prove its on the other?

Comment: Technically, anything that proves something about all natural numbers requires induction somewhere unless it doesn't depend on the "numberness" at all. (In more technical terms, you might say it's natural or parametric in whatever is being represented by the numbers.) In this case, this is one of those examples. You can generalize the statement to an arbitrary indexing set.

Answer (score 1):

Just take an arbitrary element in $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ and prove that this element is in $A$. Do the same with an arbitrary element in $B$ and prove that it belongs to $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$

Note that $x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ if there is a $k$ such that $x\in A_k$ and $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$ if $x\in A_i$ for all $i$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this requires induction.

Let $x \in B$. Since $B \subset A_i$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we have $x \in A_i$ for all $i = 1,\ldots, n$. But then $x \in \cap^n_{i=1} A_i.$ That is, $x \in B \implies x \in \cap^n_{i=1} A_i$, so $B \subset \cap^n_{i=1} A_i.$

Let $x \in \cup^n_{i=1} A_i$. Then $x \in A_j$ for some $j \in \{1,\ldots,n \}$. But since $A_j \subset A$, this implies that $x \in A$. Hence $x \in \cup^n_{i=1} A_i \implies x \in A$, so $\cup^n_{i=1} A_i\subset A.$